# PowerShell Code failing to retrieve the entire XML column data

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, powershell-3.0

I have a requirement to read a XML column from a SQL Server table, and update  a table in a different SQL Server database.

Following is the simplified version of the code. What is happening is I’m NOT getting the entire XML value. I need a way to increase XML variable length. The value in `$TargetXMLPValue` gets truncated.

```
$sqlSource = "select XMLColumn from T1 where Id = 788"
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'SourceServer' -Query $sql -ConnectionTimeout 60 -QueryTimeout 99999

$TargetXMLValue = $result.XMLColumn

$sqlTarget = "Update t2 where AnotherXMLColumn = $TargetXMLValue where ID=788"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'TargetServer' -Query $sqlTarget -ConnectionTimeout 60 -QueryTimeout 99999
```

Comment: Is the XML already truncated in `$result.XMLColumn`? In `$TargetXMLValue`? Or in the destination table? To which length is it truncated? Can give an example of original XML and where it gets cut off (provided the sample strings aren't too long)? Also, please fix your sample code. What you posted can't possibly work.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar. The XML is truncated at $result.XMLColumn.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! It is nothing to do with XML data type. I had to use MAXCHARLENGTH switch to increase the width of resulting column.

$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'SourceServer' -Query $sql -ConnectionTimeout 60 -QueryTimeout 99999 **`-MaxCharLength`** 20000